# Equivalent of mysql max and min functions in mongo?

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

How can i write the below query in mongo?

```
select max(priority) as max, min(priority) as min from queue group by user
```

I'll highly appreciate if you provide a solution in PHP.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Queries like this are performed with the aggregation framwework and the [`.aggregate()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/aggregate/) method. They use a [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) pipeline stage with the [**`$min`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/) and [**`$max`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) operators.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$user",
        "max": { "$max": "$priority" },
        "min": { "$min": "$priority" }
    }}
])
```

Or more to PHP syntax:

```php
$collection->aggregate(array(
    array(
        '$group' => array (
            '_id' => '$user',
            'max' => array( '$max' => '$priority' ),
            'min' => array( '$min' => '$priority' )
        )
    )
));
```

Also see the [SQL to Aggregation Mapping Chart](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/) in the documentation